# Passing a function to defimpl "for" option

Tags: elixir

I have following code:

```
defprotocol Reversible do
  @doc "Reverses data structure"
  def reverse(term)
end

defimpl Reversible, for: [List, Map] do
  def reverse(term), do: Enum.reverse(term)
end
```

It works fine, but I want to list all enumerable types in some way and use them in other places too.

So I tried to do this:

```
# constants.ex
defmodule Constants do
  @enumerables [List, Map]
  def enumerables, do: @enumerables
end

# reversible.ex
import Constants, only: [enumerables: 0]

defprotocol Reversible do
  def reverse(term)
end

defimpl Reversible, for: enumerables() do
  def reverse(term), do: Enum.reverse(term)
end
```

And I've got an error:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/reversible.ex ==
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Module.concat/2

    The following arguments were given to Module.concat/2:

        # 1
        Reversible

        # 2
        [List, Map]

    (elixir) lib/module.ex:562: Module.concat/2
    lib/reversible.ex:8: (file)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121:
      anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defimpl` checks the value of `for` argument [at compile time](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/12feb7bdb15c67eec1fa9f95694b24e9ac8be31f/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4241-L4245) (macro argument) [and if it's a list, it recurses over all items of the list](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/12feb7bdb15c67eec1fa9f95694b24e9ac8be31f/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L547-L555). Since your variable is not a literal list, `defimpl` does not treat it as a list.

You can work around this problem by iterating over the list and invoking `defimpl` on each yourself:

```
# constants.ex
defmodule Constants do
  @enumerables [List, Map]
  def enumerables, do: @enumerables
end

# reversible.ex
defprotocol Reversible do
  def reverse(term)
end

for enumerable <- Constants.enumerables do
  defimpl Reversible, for: enumerable do
    def reverse(term), do: Enum.reverse(term)
  end
end
```

Test:

```
$ iex -S mix
iex(1)> Reversible.reverse [1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
iex(2)> Reversible.reverse %{1 => 2, 3 => 4}
[{3, 4}, {1, 2}]
```

Comment: I thought that solution will involve re-implementing `defimpl` in some way and messing with quote/unquote. Your solution is simple and clean, thank you!